# Autofiltering with multiple variables VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, filtering, autofilter

So i am trying to filter on the same column multiple variables. I use a Userform with selections for products:

```
If PT1.value = True Then
ProductType1 = "Product 1"
Else
ProductType1 = ""
End If
If PT2.Value = True Then
ProductType2 = "Product 2"
Else
ProductType2 = ""
End If
If PT3.Value = True Then
ProductType3 = "Product 3"
Else
ProductType3 = ""
End If
        
    If ProductType <> "" Then
        TD.Range("A3:BL3").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("*" & ProductType1 & "*", "*" & ProductType2 & "*", "*" & ProductType3 & "*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
```

so essentially, if they select PT1, then the first variable becomes ProductType1 and so on

if producttype1 and producttype2 have a value, but producttype3 doesn't then it doesn't return anything, however, removing producttype 3 from the code does return filtered results. how can i get it to remove the error of a blank variable?

Comment: Post an image of part of your table including  field 7, and some more clear examples.

Comment: The issue here is that a 'Criteria1 array' is limited to accept only two elements with wild characters. A workaround, If you're happy with hiding rows, would be to loop through the cells of the column and combine the matching cells into a range and finally hide the entire rows of the combined range. Another workaround, if you have a column with unique values, would be to loop through the cells of the criteria column and on each match write the corresponding value of the unique column to an array (dictionary) and then filter by this array (dictionary: `dict.Keys`) in the unique column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (not tested):

### Option 1

```
Sub test1()
    Const delim = "|"
    Dim s As String: s = ""
    
    If PT1.Value Then s = s & "Product 1"
    If PT2.Value Then s = s & IIf(s = "", "", delim) & "Product 2"
    If PT3.Value Then s = s & IIf(s = "", "", delim) & "Product 3"
        
    If s <> "" Then
        TD.Range("A3:BL3").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Split(s, delim), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If
End Sub
```

### Option 2

```
Sub test2()
    If PT1.Value Or PT2.Value Or PT3.Value Then
        TD.Range("A3:BL3").AutoFilter Field:=7, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
            Criteria1:=Array(IIf(PT1.Value, "Product 1", Empty), _
                             IIf(PT2.Value, "Product 2", Empty), _
                             IIf(PT3.Value, "Product 3", Empty))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for replying. Unfortunately I have realised (as well as others commenting) that I can't have more than 2 wildcard when autofiltering